# Limite de transmision de datos e IFrames

Tags: html, html5, pdf, hosting, xhtml

estoy haciendo pruebas con hosts gratuitos y como sabeis tienen un límite de transmisión de datos.
Mi pregunta es, si creo un PDF, lo subo a una página de terceros o incluso a Drive y lo meto en un IFrame,¿cargar ese archivo lo paga el servidor de terceros o mi host?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta simple es no. El tráfico de datos en un servidor es generado únicamente por los archivos almacenados dentro del mismo servidor. Lo que respecta a las peticiones que se realizan a dichos archivos. Ésto incluye ficheros PHP, HTML, CSS, etc.

Una de las formas de prevenir el consumo total del anco de banda limitado en un servidor gratuito es almacenar los archivos externamente solo para ser incluidos en el resultado HTML final siendo así cargados desde otro servidor. (Imágenes y documentos)

Algo muy usado en desarrollos web avanzados son las famosas CDN's. Ésto implica cargar archivos CSS, JavaScript, etc.. desde el servidor oficial del creador.

Te dejo algunos enlaces para que puedas informarte mejor.

**Ancho de banda:**

http://blog.hostdime.com.co/por-que-es-tan-importante-el-ancho-de-banda-en-un-servidor-web/amp/

https://whm.mx/que-es-el-ancho-de-banda/

**CDN's:**

https://www.hostingexperto.es/que-es-un-cdn/

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero